# What is the best method to use to store a X509Certificate value to later retrieve that certificate

Tags: ssl, x509certificate2

At the moment I am storing the SerialNumber of a certificate which I then use within my application to get the certificate to use it.

I just wondered, best practices speaking, what should I be storing to later retrieve the certificate?

ThumbPrint?
SerialNumber?
SerialNumber and Issuer?

The enum `X509FindType` contains many FindByxxx But not many seem would return a distinct certificate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I myself use FindByThumbprint at the moment but I was wondering about the exact same issue as you're having.

Comment: The thumbprint of a certificate is a hash of its body IIRC. This will *always* return a distinct certificate. Therefore, you should be using the thumbprint.